# Create two new columns via calculate field and the split function

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator

Based on the data below, how can I split the `NAME` column (in a dataset) to two new columns using `calculate field` and the `split function`? So, any thing before the comma goes under the new column `Census_Tract` and anything after the comma goes under the new column `County`.

Sample data:

```
NAME
Census tract 1111, San Diego California
Census tract 2222, San Diego California
Census tract 4444, San Diego California
Census tract 1024.54, San Diego California
```

Desired output:

```
Census_tract          County
Census tract 1111     San Diego California
Census tract 2222     San Diego California
Census tract 4444     San Diego California
Census tract 1024.54  San Diego California
```

Comment: For the Census Tract field, the expression would be `!NAME!.split(',')[0]` and for the County field the expression would be `!NAME!.split(',')[1]`

Comment: Cheers, please put your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the [Calculate Field (Data Management) - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm) `expression` parameter works with simple Python commands, this can be done without having to use a `code_block`.  Using [str.split() - Built-in Types - Python 3.x documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```py
# expression block for Census Tract
!NAME!.split(',')[0]

# expression block for County
!NAME!.split(',')[1]
```